# How to change CSS properties from within django HTML template logic

Tags: css, django

Newbie question I presume: How do I change some CSS property (// *change background image of parent div*) of the parent element from within the logic in the HTML template? Do I really need to implement JS for this?

```
        <div class="exercise-items-wrapper">

            {% if error %}
                {{ error }}
            {% else %}
                {% for x in exercise %}

                    <div class="exercise-item">
                    
                        {{x.name}}

                        {% if x.primary_focus == 'CO' %}
                            // change background image of parent div
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if x.friend_verified %}
                            <img src="{% static 'main/images/fv.svg' %}" height="14px">
                        {% endif %}

                        <p  id="exercise-level" class="exercise-level">lv. VII</p>

                        {% if x.video_verified %}
                            <img src="{% static 'main/images/vv.svg' %}" height="14px">
                        {% endif %}

                    </div>
                    


                {% endfor %}

            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by parent div you're referring to the `div` with class `exercise-item`, then the way I've always done this is to simply also write the if-then template block within the class attribute:

```
<div class="exercise-item {% if x.primary_focus == 'CO' %}special-background-class{% endif %}">
```

And then define `special-background-class` in your CSS. Admittedly it doesn't look nice to read, but it works and it's much more maintainable than anything that has to use JS, unless your JS is already well-integrated into your Django app.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware it was even an option to write logic within the tags themselves. I don't care (much) about the readability :)